# Expo React-native error - This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified ios 16

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, expo, eas

I've created iOS internal distribution build with eas using command `eas build --profile development --platform ios` but getting integrity verification error.

[Build link](https://expo.dev/accounts/atifgk/projects/yeti-app/builds/518a166b-d4d2-4f17-82ab-e7adbcf94b5f)

[image]

I'm trying to run development with local code. Working fine for Android but facing issue on iPhone.

Thanks

Comment: Have you included your device UDID in the provisioning profile. Does the device have developer mode enabled?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes i have enabled developer mode and also profile stuff

Comment: @MuhammadAtif did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register your iphone before install the build

- eas device:create

Now you can build new one to have your iphone include.

If you want to have it on old build then you need to resign the UDID you created on that old build

- eas build:resign --profile "development" --platform ios

Here are the docs - https://docs.expo.dev/build/internal-distribution/ https://docs.expo.dev/app-signing/app-credentials/#re-signing-new-credentials